# How to create Json objects from foreach $_POST loop

Tags: php, html, json

i have made some random input names, because its a drag and drop page builder, so i can't guess, how much elements user will use, so i have created a random input names, 
for that am using php foreach loop for $_POST requests. i have tried to make it encoded into json and then later save it into database. but it looks like something is wrong in my json.
Here are my html demo codes :

```
<input style="display:none;" name="DATA-BLOCK-A(some random string)">
<input style="display:none;" name="DATA-BLOCK-B(some random string)">
```

PS: A is for selecting element A, and B is for element B.

here is my PHP code :

```
if (isset($_POST)) {
    //$arr = array();
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
    {

     $arr = array($key => $value);
     $encode = json_encode($arr);
    echo $encode;
    }


}
```

and Here is the result :

```
{"sortlist":"block[]=D5e3385b75a75d&block[]=K5e3385b85a75e&block[]=C5e3385b95a75f&block[]=F5e3385ba5a760"}{"save_cont_flag":"0"}{"DATA-block-D5e3385b75a75d":"0#TRANSP

<\/p>"}{"DATA-block-K5e3385b85a75e":"0#TRANSP20"}{"DATA-block-C5e3385b95a75f":"01#TRANSP0images\/250place.jpg\u00b8"}{"text-1573532276681":""}{"textarea-1573532278320":""}{"DATA-block-F5e3385ba5a760":"121212unundefined"}{"page_name":"123"}{"aff_link":""}{"pause_link":""}{"seo_title":""}{"fbook":""}{"seo_desc":""}{"seo_keywords":""}{"back_color":"#EEEEEE"}{"body_color":"#FFFFFF"}{"back_image":""}{"ty_font_color":"#000000"}{"ty_override":""}{"ty_name":"12314"}{"ty_stm":""}{"modal_para_width":"0"}{"catcha_url":""}{"catcha_un":"Yes"}{"catcha_message":""}{"code_head":""}{"code_body":""}{"modal_share_width":"0"}{"modal_cta_width":"0"}{"modal_video_width":"0"}{"modal_mp_width":"0"}{"modal_stm_width":"0"}{"modal_image_width":"0"}{"modal_bonus_width":"1"}{"ty_headline":""}{"modal_spacer_width":"0"}{"att_bar_status":"0"}{"att_delay_in":"0"}{"att_bar_color":"#bbbbbb"}{"att_gradient":"0"}{"att_text_color":"#000000"}{"att_text_font":"Open Sans:400"}{"att_text_size":"14"}{"att_bar_message":"Add Your Attention Bar Text Here"}{"att_link_color":"#000000"}{"att_link_label":"Add Link Text Here"}{"att_link_url":"http:\/\/commissiongorilla.com"}{"count_font":"Open Sans:800"}{"count_size":"55"}{"count_status":"0"}{"count_type":"0"}{"count_end":"01\/31\/2020 6:41 AM"}{"count_zone":"0.0"}{"count_eg_days":"0"}{"count_eg_hours":"0"}{"count_eg_mins":"0"}{"count_digit_color":"#bbbbbb"}{"count_label_color":"#bbbbbb"}{"count_background":"0"}{"count_language":"1"}{"count_exp":"0"}{"count_url":"http:\/\/commissiongorilla.com"}{"count_add_days":"0"}{"count_add_hours":"0"}{"count_add_mins":"0"}{"modal_countdown_width":"0"}{"modal_review_width":"0"}
```

and also how seperate all A BLOCKS and B BLOCKS?
Thanks.!

Comment: Where does that `<\/p>` come form? Sounds like a missing quote in the form field attribute

Comment: that's the value of DATA-block-D5e3385b75a75d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use a loop.

Just used `json_encode` :

```
$json = json_encode($_POST);
```

If you need to get `key` contain `DATA-block-`, you can write :

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos($key, 'DATA-block-') !== false) {
        // Here `DATA-block-{}`
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you change the input names to `DATA-BLOCK-A[]` and `DATA-BLOCK-B[]`, `$_POST['DATA-BLOCK-A']` will contain an array of all a blocks and `$_POST['DATA-BLOCK-B']` will contain an array of all b blocks.

This also eliminates the need for generating random strings.

Comment: That will not work, as you can see in the result, i am sorting the elements. like i have two blocks "block[]=D5e3385b75a75d&block[]=K5e3385b85a75e" and block D5e3385b75a75d will be at number 1 and K5e3385b85a75e will be at number 2 when i will call them from database to show contents.